# Angular PrimeNG - Show tooltip on select all checkbox in multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng

I wanted to show a tooltip "Select All" for the top checkbox under multiselect dropdown.

[image]

Below is the demo code provided in the PrimeNG documentation

.html

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" optionLabel="name"></p-multiSelect>
```

.ts

```
        export class MultiSelectDemo {

        cities: City[];

        selectedCities: City[];

        constructor() {
            this.cities = [
                {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
                {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
                {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
                {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
                {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
            ];
        }

    }
```

Can someone please help on how we can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A stackblitz would be helpfull here

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo?file=README.md

Comment: primeng have its demo stackblitz.. just need to target the top checkbox and add a tooltip to it

Answer (score 1):

You could disabkle the default checkbox:

```
[showToggleAll]="false"
```

Then add another template for the header, that includes it's own checkbox doing the toggle and having the tooltip

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <p-checkbox
      pTooltip="toggle all"
      [value]="false"
      (click)="ms.toggleAll()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </ng-template>
```

forked demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-q7xycc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you. But what does it mean by [value]="false" and ms.toggleAll() ?

Comment: `[value]="false"` is just the hold value of the checkbox and `ms.toggleAll()` is the toogleAll functionality when you click the checkbox. `ms` is the reference to the `p-multiselect`, I added the `#ms`on the `p-multiselect`tag here.

Comment: Okay. If we need to have the pTemplate for header, we need to set the template for items too in another ng-template? If I add only header, I am getting two checkboxes for each row for every item.

Comment: Acually I have a <p-table> in which there is a <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>. Within this, there is a <th *ngFor="let column of columns; let i=index>". And in that <th> i have my <p-multiSelect>. Is this any issue for using <ng-template> inside another ?

Comment: "If I add only header, I am getting two checkboxes for each row for every item" -- for that I told you to `[showToggleAll]="false"`, to remove the original checkbox

Comment: My problem is, instead of adding a checkbox in the header, it is adding in each row with results like for each country there are two checkboxes and no checkbox in the header. Seems like some issue with my code.

Comment: Our application actually using primeng 9.1.3 version. Will this be an issue as the pTemplate="header" is not working?

Comment: Acutally I am facing a compilation error for (click)="ms.toggleAll()". Saying it is Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Any workaround for this?